# import oauth2client ImportError: No module named oauth2client

Tags: python

I am working on a python program for extracting stuff from the cloud.  As such I am using

```
google-api-python-client
```

I have successfully installed that, however when I run my program I get the error message

```
ImportError: No module named oauth2client
```

I have 2 issues with that error. Firstly,  I had oauth2client install prior to installing google-api-python-client. Secondly,  oauth2client  gets install as a requirement for google-api.

My first thoughts were that there was some conflict so I uninstalled both programs and installed google-api-python-client alone. This should resolve any conflicts ? Still no joy. Although as I am uninstalling and installing the program I repeatedly see this warning

```
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\078861~1.025\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_07886187\oauth2client\setup.py) egg_info for package oauth2client

warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'tests'
```

I feel this is a crucial clue but not sure what it means. I did a quick search and I have a number of tests folders in the site packages related to a number of other libraries , is there any way that they are interfering with the correct implantation of oauth2client ? Any insight would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Just for information,
oauth2client can be installed just by running command `pip install oauth2client`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO eventually figured it out , said that I would leave this marker for anyone coming after me. I was running the script from the python34 directory where I had the file stored, however I was using git Bash , and that uses the python that is in the environmental variables, regardless of where it is called from. I had python2.7 in the environmental variables.